# Extremal curves in the plane which make a line integral stationary

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

The Question

---

Consider the extremal curves in the plane which make the line integral
$$I=\int_P^Q \left(y^2dx+\frac{dy}{dx}dy\right)$$
stationary, where $P=(0,2)$ and $Q=(1,b)\ (b>0)$. To do so, first rewrite the integral in the standard form of the fundamental problem of variational calculus, involving $y(x)$. Then obtain the form of the curve(s).

---

**Problem**

I have been given the above question, I am posting on here to see if anyone can offer some advice as to where/ how to start with this problem, as I am clueless, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the problem as

$$
I = \int_{P}^Q \left(y^2\frac{dx}{dt}dt + \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} \frac{dy}{dt}dt \right) = \int_P^Q \left(y^2x' + \frac{y'^2}{x'}\right)dt = \int_P^Q L(x,y,x',y')dt
$$

Where $L$ is given by

$$
L = y^2x' + \frac{y'^2}{x'}
$$

To solve this problem you can use the Euler-Lagrange equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} &=& 0  \\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x'}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray}

For example, the first equation becomes

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(2\frac{y'}{x'}\right) - (2yx') = 0
$$

Rearranging we arrive to

$$
y(t) x'(t)^2+\frac{x''(t) y'(t)}{x'(t)}=y''(t) \tag{1}
$$

Similarly for the $x$:

$$
x''(t) y'(t)-x'(t) y''(t)+y(t) x'(t)^3=0 \tag{2}
$$

Looking at this, probably your best bet is to solve them numerically

Comment: May be a stupid question, but is this a solvable differential equation?

Comment: I'm assuming this will involve integration?

Comment: Also, will I have to repeat the process with the second equation?

Comment: @George yes, that’s what I mean by ‘write the equation for $x$’: replace $L$ in the second equation above

Comment: I have gotten the following result from the second equation, but am unsure as of what to do next:$ \frac{-1}{x'^2 + 2 y} y'^2 + y^2 y'' + \frac{(2 y'y'')}{x}$

Comment: @George Seems that I made a mistake (sorry about that), I think you can only solve this numerically. Look at the updated version

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_P^Q \left(y^2dx+\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx} dx\right);\quad  L= y^2 +y ^{'2} $$
Apply Euler- Lagrage equation in Beltrami $x$ independence form

$$  y^2 +y ^{'2} - y^{'} (2  y^{'}) = const = a^2; \quad y^{'} = \sqrt{y^2-c^2} ;$$

$$ x = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-c^2}} = \cosh^{-1}\frac {y}{c} + h ;$$

$$ y = c \cosh (x-h) $$

which is a catenary equation with arbitrary constants $c,h$.

Say given $b=3$ we have two points of catenary $(0,2), (1,3)$

There are 2 equations to numerically solve for $(c,h)$

$$ 2= c \cosh (h), 3= c \cosh (1-h)$$

Comment: Is it possible to find the constants given the initial conditions above?

Comment: Also, what is c (another arbitrary constant?)

Comment: Yes to both. The catenary has two arbitrary constants. When two points (from which the cable hangs) and two equations are given arbitrary constants $b,c$ can be numerically found out.

Comment: how would one find these constants, given that P=(0,2)  and Q=(1,b) (b>0)

Comment: $b$ is a given constant ! ( given height of upper point of fixity).

Comment: oh yes, im just being stupid haha, is there any way of finding c?

Comment: Sorry my error in using same symbol $b$, Its now corrected as $h$ for shift along $x$ axis